# How to activate Window started by another process

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi

I think this might be impossible. Please proof me wrong.

Following setup:

- My .NET C# Application with GUI (lets call it `gui`) opens another application (lets call it `server`) by creating a `new Process()`
- The `server` (developed by somebody else) is started with a parameter to hide its GUI
- The `gui` waits for the user to make some inputs
- The `gui` then commands the `server` to perform some tasks
- Those tasks are defined in an assembly/DLL which i provide to the `server`
- One of those tasks is to open a Form/Dialog and ask the user some more questions

Now because the whole userexperience needs to be optimized for repeated operation, the GUI elements (windows/forms/dialogs) that open need to be pre-selected/focused/active.

The first problem arises as i did not find a clear explanation of what the [difference between those](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3940346/7926064) properties (Focus, Active, Selected, TopMost) is.

Now the real question is, how can i ensure that all GUI elements are active and selected, regardless of whether they are started by my `gui` process or the `server` process?

Using the WINAPI can be more powerful i read so i defined the following

```
// required to use WINAPI for RegainFocus();
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hwnd);
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr SetActiveWindow(IntPtr hwnd);
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

static private void RegainFocus()
{
    // set focus back to and show application for faster input
    // SW_RESTORE = 9
    ShowWindow(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle, 9);
    SetForegroundWindow(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle);
    SetActiveWindow(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle);
}
```

Then what i have tried so far is:

- Set the `StartInfo` of the `server` process like this (so the new process does not steal the focus of `gui`)

  > ```
  > myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
  > myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
  > myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
  > ```
- Start the `server` process and `WaitForInputIdle` (like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8910385/7926064)) to assure that the `server` is really ready
- Also use `RegainFocus()` in the `gui` app
- In the DLL for the `server` i create a new `Form()` and try (to bring the window to front and have it selected)

  > ```
  > myForm = new Form();
  > myForm.Activated += dialog_Activated;
  > myForm.PerformLayout();
  > myForm.TopMost = true;
  > myForm.Activate();
  > myForm.BringToFront();
  > myForm.Focus();
  > myForm.Select();
  > DialogResult result = myForm.ShowDialog();
  > ```
- The `TopMost=true` works in bringing the dialog in front of `gui`
- The `dialog_Activated()` method sets the Focus on the first input control using `FocusControl()`. This works.

The result of this is a window on top of my `gui` which has the cursor blinking in the first input control but is deselected/inactive. When i hit `<TAB>` i can see a different control gets selected in the `gui` which is in the background.

I tried spraying `RegainFocus()` calls in the Form as well, didnt work.

Further ideas that i have but no way of achieving them:

- Defocus the `gui` once the input is done there, but [there is no](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1140277/7926064) `unFocus()`
- override [some important events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41477545/7926064) in my Form class, but [how and which](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25219414/7926064) ones?

Target Framework is .NET 4.5, target operating systems are Windows 7 and Windows 10.

Thank you for any help and inputs/tipps!

Comment: See [Window Features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/window-features). Also relevant: [Foreground activation permission is like love: You can’t steal it, it has to be given to you](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090220-00/?p=19083).

Comment: Note that `Form.BringToFront` etc has no effect while the form is not shown yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got a solution which seems to work on Windows 10 and Windows 7.

After my focus is lost i use the `RegainFocus()` function to regain focus (and have the window activated), see question. Attention: dont mix process `HANDLE` and `MainWindowHandle`. When an object is hidden, its `MainWindowHandle` might very well be `0`.

I removed

```
    myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

when starting the `server` process in order of not messing with the visibility state. I kept `[WaitForInputIdle][1]` though.

On Windows 7, this was still not enough, and [AllowSetForegroundWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-allowsetforegroundwindow) on the created process did not work (thanks for the comments though), instead of bringing the window to the front, the [taskbar was flashing](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-flashing-taskbar-buttons-windows). The solution here was to [set the registry value](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/929#issuecomment-331854403) of

```
\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\ForegroundLockTimeout
```

to `0` and restarting the machine. Then the code behaved the same for Windows 7 and 10. With the right permissions, this could even be [done programatically](http://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20060603-ProblemsWithSetForegroundWindowCalls.html).

Since this problem has so many different answers and solutions, i assume that it depends on many factors (like windows version, registry setup, probably UAC and theme settings, framework and runtime, some [more conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19136480/7926064), ...) and this is why i want to mention the other approaches i found as well.

- [Minimizing](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2867#issuecomment-153918442) the window before showing it
- [Simulating a keypress](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30572826/7926064) before `SetForegroundWindow`
- [Sending](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21156860/7926064) a `WM_SHOWWINDOW` message
- `ShowWindow` with `SW_RESTORE` and `SW_SHOW` [before](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9a455203-8c67-457a-8b0c-fbf06a75b0b2/setforegroundwindowintptr-hwnd-not-working-when-application-in-notification-area?forum=wpf) `SetForegroundWindow`
- A [combination](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3772233/7926064) of `[SetWindowPos][10]`, `SetActiveWindow`, `SetFocus` and finally `AttachThreadInput`
- [Use](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12323882/7926064) `AllowSetForegroundWindow` with `[ASFW_ANY][11]`
- [Disable SetForegroundWindow](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32/L7h_YWOE7hY/kTKVI_93YhUJ) locking
- [Use](https://ronniediaz.com/2011/05/03/start-a-process-in-the-foreground-in-c-net-without-appactivate/) `AppActivate` [from VB.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.appactivate?view=netframework-4.7.2) [in C#](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8de1bd2c-946f-404f-8dc3-73a75b687fa1/is-it-ok-to-use-interactionappactivate-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral)
- [Override Form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25219414/7926064) to be topmost